# Encrypt / decrypt in perl

Tags: perl, encryption

I am trying to make a script somewhat more user friendly as it asks me to enter my password each and every time. I want to enter the password, write it to file encrypted, and read it back decrypted.

I googled it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/encryption-and-decryption-in-perl/) so I tried to get this in. Unfortunately the decode_base64 does not return the password I typed in.

Is was hoping there would be a very simple way of encrypting/decrypting in perl. Can somebody help me out?

For reference, the adjustments I made

encrypt:

```
my $msg = "Enter password for ".$ENV{'USERNAME'}.": ";
UTILS_print( $msg );
# Do not show the password 
ReadMode('noecho');
chomp($password = ReadLine());
ReadMode('normal');

# Store encrypted password 
if (open(FILE, '>', "$pwdFile")) {
    
    my $hidden = crypt $password, join "",  
        ('.', '/', 0..9, 'A'..'Z', 'a'..'z') [rand 64, rand 64]; 
    print FILE $hidden;
    close(FILE);
}
```

decrypt:

```
# Use a stored password when no password is set during start of script
my $pwdFile = 'c:/Localdata/nexus_upload_'.$ENV{'USERNAME'}.'.pwd';
if ( $password eq '' ) {
    if ( -e "$pwdFile"  ) {
        if (open(FILE, "$pwdFile")) {
            my @lines = <FILE>;
            close(FILE);
            $password = $lines[0];
            chomp $password;
            $password = decode_base64($password);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for the [`crypt()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/crypt) function:

> **crypt PLAINTEXT,SALT**
>
> Creates a digest string exactly like the crypt(3) function in the C library (assuming that you actually have a version there that has not been extirpated as a potential munition).
>
> `crypt` is a one-way hash function. The PLAINTEXT and SALT are turned into a short string, called a digest, which is returned. The same PLAINTEXT and SALT will always return the same string, but there is no (known) way to get the original PLAINTEXT from the hash. Small changes in the PLAINTEXT or SALT will result in large changes in the digest.
>
> There is no decrypt function. This function isn't all that useful for cryptography (for that, look for Crypt modules on your nearby CPAN mirror) and the name "crypt" is a bit of a misnomer. Instead it is primarily used to check if two pieces of text are the same without having to transmit or store the text itself. An example is checking if a correct password is given. The digest of the password is stored, not the password itself. The user types in a password that is crypt'd with the same salt as the stored digest. If the two digests match, the password is correct.

Note that it says "There is no decrypt function".

The web page that you are getting this code from is talking nonsense. If you run the sample code from that page, you get this output:

```
Encrypted Password :: B2rm1NvmFuLww
Decrypted Password :: j������
Password In Plain Text :: GeeksforGeeks
```

It doesn't work.

The `decode()` function from [MIME::Base64](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Base64) is the inverse of the `encode()` function from the same module. You could use that to "disguise" your password in a file on your disk, but it's certainly not encryption and it really won't add any security.

Alternatively, follow the advice in the documentation and look at modules in the "Crypt" namespace.

Comment: Ah OK, so that explains why it doesn't work for me. Thanks for the explanation! I'll look at the Crypt module. Thx